# Pardot / Salesforce Integration Best Practises

Tags: lightning, pardot

I'm looking to get some feedback on our integration plan for Pardot/Salesforce from some more seasoned Salesforce integrators. We've asked our integration partner these questions, and didn't get a real response.

We have Pardot setup, and linked to Salesforce. Prospects in Pardot sync over to Salesforce, including their custom keys we set.

We want to push Prospects into Pardot with Form Handlers from our marketing site. When users convert to trials in our product we want to push specific metrics of that client into Pardot as well. Engagement metrics of their onboarding, for example: Invited extra users, has published something, etc.

- Is it best practise to just update those Prospects in Pardot and have them sync over to Salesforce's Lead?
- Should we be creating Leads from our product (and deal with Opportunities/Accounts/Contacts)? Or do we leave that to our sales reps?

Any feedback or guide in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I always try to look at the Pardot + Salesforce integration as a big funnel. It is similar to how Pardot displays their lifecycle report:

[image: Pardot lifecycle report]

The first 2 stages you only want to involve your marketing team. You want them to nurture your prospects. At a given point in time, when the prospect's score is considered high enough and he has a good grade, you'll want to push that prospect to your sales team.

That's the moment you assign a user, triggering the sync to Salesforce, creating a lead over there (MQL) which is then assigned to a sales user (or queue).

Once the sales people feel there is a chance to close a deal, they'll convert the lead into a account/contact/opportunity (SQL). Closing that deal is the last stage of the funnel.